# Syntax error near unexpected token 'elif' shell script

Tags: shell

I am facing the syntax error near unexpected token,elif error for the following code.

```
if [ "$1" == "abc" ]; then

   echo "abc"

elif [ "$1" == "xyz" ]; then

   echo "xyz"

else 

    echo "Unkown parameter"
    exit 0

fi
```

Error is:
abc.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
abc.sh: line 28:`elif [ "$1" == "xyz" ]; then

Comment: This error has been discussed. Please search in previous posts.

Comment: I have run that code and I'm not getting any errors:   $ cat sh.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "abc" ]; then

   echo "abc"

elif [ "$1" == "xyz" ]; then

   echo "xyz"

else

    echo "Unkown parameter"
    exit 0

fi
$ ./sh.sh abc
abc
$ ./sh.sh xyz
xyz
$ ./sh.sh a
Unkown parameter

Comment: Does using `=` instead of `==` help? (POSIX specifies `=` bash/etc. allow `==` for compatibility though.) If not then this code snippet is valid and the error lies somewhere else and/or in something that didn't paste cleanly (DOS line endings, odd non-printing characters, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Code seems alright but only point I would like to add is the OS on which you are running. The == works fine with Linux RedHat/Suse or some solaris machine but on some OS like Hpux or AIX it don't work. You should use = which is correct as you are comparing strings.